# John chapter 11: Where was Lazarus when he was dead?

Tags: death

The purpose of Jesus' raising Lazarus from the dead was to show the power of God over death. The Jewish (Pharisaic) belief at the time was the spirit lingered over the body for three days. The four days in the tomb was to show that Lazarus was 'most sincerely dead' - to remove any doubt about comas or other near death phenomena. The question arises: where was Lazarus during these four days? Was he in Heaven, Hell, or some other place. The Catholics may reply that he was in Limbo but would this answer satisfy Protestants?

Comment: First, please cite a source for the following belief: "The Jewish (Pharisaic) belief at the time was the spirit lingered over the body for three days." Next, your last sentence is not quite appropriate for Biblical Hermeneutics.

Comment: I would suggest asking what Protestants believe about this on Christianity SE. It is not really a hermeneutics question.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps the answer can be found in the account of the Rich Man & Lazarus (I am not confusing the Lazarus in the question with the account that Jesus gave.) Only that there appears a place or compartment that Jesus described where the saints of old (believers) waited.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics SE, thanks for contributing! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://goo.gl/5U2gsX) to learn more about us. We're a [little different](http://goo.gl/wCxRAv) from other SEs. Our community looks for answers to reflect a good degree of research and references. Typically, we like answers that cite scholarly references and/or explain how your interpretation arises from the text. Don't just tell us [*what*](http://goo.gl/VRkT4c) you know, tell us [*how*](http://goo.gl/BoMPLJ) you know it.